# Getting number of tasks in celery queue from the terminal (redis broker)

Tags: redis, ubuntu-14.04, celery

How can I retrieve **number** of tasks in a queue that are yet to be processed? The broker is redis, and I want to be able to do this in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery queues are stored in redis as lists, so you can use the `redis-cli` tool to check the length of the list. For a queue named `my_queue` you'd run `redis-cli llen my_queue`. Check out the [docs on monitoring](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-redis-queues).